# Is It Possible to Partially Escape the output string using {{ .. }} and {!! .. !!} in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, escaping, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I am using Laravel 5.7. `Route` is not working inside unescaped `{!! .. !!}`. Look at the `href='{{url('/')}}'` part which is being rendered as `%7B%7Burl(`. In my `Controller` I have the following code:

**Conroller**

```
$navbar = '';
foreach($navs as $nav){
  $navbar .= "
   <li class='nav-item'>
    <a class='nav-link' href='{{url('/')}}'>".$nav->name."</a>
   </li>
  ";
}
return view('front/index', ['navbar' => $navbar]);
```

In my `blade` file I have the following code:

**Blade**

```
<ul>
  {!! $navbar !!}
</ul>
```

Everything else is fine except the `{{url('/')}}` part. In my `Blade` file `{{url('/')}}` renders as something like `%7B%7B(url`. I understand why is this happening. But my question is, is there any way to make `{{url('/')}}` to work.

Comment: You can't use blade directives inside of another blade directive like that. In fact, I don't think there's a way to get that blade directive inside of the navbar like that. You probably want to create a nav blade separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you mix PHP and Blade. Try this:

```
$navbar = '';
foreach($navs as $nav){
  $navbar .= "<li class='nav-item'>";
  $navbar .= "<a class='nav-link' href=' ".url('/')." '>".$nav->name."</a>";
  $navbar .= "</li>";  
}
return view('front/index', ['navbar' => $navbar]);
```

or even to prevent quotes related mistakes:

```
$navbar = '';
$url = url('/');
foreach($navs as $nav){
  $navbar .= "<li class='nav-item'>";
  $navbar .= "<a class='nav-link' href=' ".$url." '>".$nav->name."</a>";
  $navbar .= "</li>";  
}
return view('front/index', ['navbar' => $navbar]);
```

Of course, this answer aim to solve your specific problem. I recommend taking a look at the other answers too.

Comment: I think this comment can be improved by specifying that this fix is not recommended. it maybe a working fix, but using this method may cause more confusion in future projects, and would not help the them in writing better code.

Comment: @GroverReyes, I understand your point here. But in my case, I am working on a dynamic navbar which is almost seven level deep (nested). So I just put the necessary code here for the sake of simplicity. Real scenario is far more complicated. I know this is not the standard and not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel we do not do frontend logic on the controller, that is a common mistake beginners typically make, Make sure that all frontend related stuff stays on the blade files or the "VIEW"

what I suggest is this..

controller file ( controller file )

```
return view('front.index', ['navbar' => $navs]);
```

front.index file ( view file )

```
<ul>
 @for($navbar as $nav)
   <li class='nav-item'>
     <a class='nav-link' href='{{ url('/') }}'>{{ $nav->name }}</a>
   </li>
 @endfor
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a nice and important tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the best idea to let blade handle all html rendering, move the `$navbar` to your blade like this:

Your controller:

```
return view('front/index', ['navs' => $navs]);
```

Your blade file:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($navs as $nav)
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('/') }}">{{ $nav->name }}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.